# Validate two controls (CustomValidator)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Before submitting the form I need to test if the sum ( txtA + txtB) is greater than 100. Is it possible to do this with a `CustomValidator`, because I don't know if I can choose the 2 textbox in controltovalidate

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtA" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtB" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" 
                     runat="server" 
                     ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" />

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can do this. Are you wanting client side or server side validation?

Comment: Server Side Validation

Answer (score 9):

you can do as :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtA" runat="server" /> 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtB" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CV1"runat="server" 
    OnServerValidate="ServerValidation" 
    ErrorMessage="Sum is less than 100" />
```

codebehind :

```
protected void ServerValidation(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = int.Parse(txtA.Text)+ int.Parse(txtB.Text) >100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you drop a custom validation in your page, you can link the validator to a control, but if you want to perform multiple validations over more than one control, you need to include the following attribute

```
 OnServerValidate="MyMethodOnServerSide"
```

and define that method on the server side

```
protected void MyMethodOnServerSide(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mytxt1.Text) &&
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(mytxt2.Text))
            {
                args.IsValid = false;
                return;
            }

            args.IsValid = true;
}
```

just asign the `args.IsValid` property to the value you need. On the other hand the validation is done before you load the page, so if you clicked a button that performs an action like reading values from the DB in case everything is correct, on that action you need to include the following check.

```
protected void cmdSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
          LoadDataFromDB();
    }
}
```

When `args.IsValid` is false then `Page.IsValid` is false too. Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You need to add another control, `<asp:HiddenField>` and then leverage `jQuery` to set the value of that control. It might look something like this:

## MARKUP

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="SumOfValues" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2"
    runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="CustomValidator"
    ControlToValidate="SumOfValues" />
```

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#txtA').change(sumValues);
    $('#txtB').change(sumValues);
});

function sumValues() {
    var val1 = $('txtA').value();
    if (val1 === undefined) { val1 = 0; }

    var val2 = $('txtB').value();
    if (val2 === undefined) { val2 = 0; }

    $('#SumOfValues').value(val1 + val2);
}
```

and that should allow you validate that hidden control. However, one thing you'll need to make sure to do on all three controls is leverage `ClientIDMode` and set it to `Static` so that the names are exactly what you specify in the markup when they get to the page.

Comment: You can't validate a hiddenfield. This isn't possible unless you make a custom hiddenfield control described here: http://simpledevlearnings.blogspot.co.il/2013/04/validate-asphiddenfield-value-with.html